# XPath join two elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm struggling with XPath a bit. In SQL term I'm trying to join two lists and select element from one list using an attribute from the other list.

My XML document:

```xml
<DOSSIER>
    <PRODUCT_DEF>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <SHOW>true</SHOW>
    </PRODUCT_DEF>
    <PRODUCT_DEF>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <SHOW>false</SHOW>
    </PRODUCT_DEF>
    <CONTRACT>
        <NUMBER>11</NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>1</PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>
    </CONTRACT>
    <CONTRACT>
        <NUMBER>22</NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>2</PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>
    </CONTRACT>
    <CONTRACT>
        <NUMBER>33</NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>2</PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>
    </CONTRACT>
    <CONTRACT>
        <NUMBER>44</NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>1</PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER>
    </CONTRACT>
</DOSSIER>
```

So I'm Trying to select all CONTRACT elements for which the corresponding PRODUCT_DEF/SHOW = true. CONTRACT_DEF/VOLGNUM is related by CONTRACT/PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER

In my attempt I'm trying to join these two elements like this, but I think it's not possible to refer to a totally different element all of a sudden within the CONTRACT element:

```
//CONTRACT[..//PRODUCT_DEF[NUMBER=./PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER]/SHOW="true"]
```

The result should be a list of two nodes, containing:

CONTRACT[NUMBER=11], 
CONTRACT[NUMBER=44]

Is this even possible? 
Perhaps I should do it in two steps?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally with XPath using `//` is a mistake (it searches *all* elements so hard to control, and also slow).

1. The basic selection is `/DOSSIER/CONTRACT[condition]` which means `condition` will have its `CONTRACT` element as context node (this is what `.` will refer to). Thus
2. To get to the `PRODUCT_DEF` node in the condition need `./PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER = ../PRODUCT_DEF/NUMBER`, but that means any sub-condition on the state of the product will use that `NUMBER`child as its context, but could apply the condition to the `PRODUCT_DEF` node. Thus
3. Expect you need something like:

   ```
   /DOSSIER/CONTRACT[./PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER = ../PRODUCT_DEF[./SHOW = 'true']/NUMBER]
   ```

However I would likely change that to use absolute paths for the `PRODUCT_DEF` as well as dropping the unnecessary `./`, to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
/DOSSIER/CONTRACT[PRODUCT_DEF_NUMBER = /DOSSIER/PRODUCT_DEF[SHOW = 'true']/NUMBER]
```

PS. I hate all caps, why do some want to preserve this artefact of ancient systems? Hence typos likely.

Comment: Ah, yes, that does the trick. Thanks!

P.S. The caps things, yeah I know, but that's what I have to work with.

Comment: Re Caps @Denno BTDTGTTS hence the comment.